# Can the Answer to Allah be in simple Mathematics?

Tags: quran, allah, science, quran-translation, theology

**If maths is the truth and God is the truth then maths must explain the truth of God.**

The only truth that mankind knows is the universal language of truth, mathematics.

> 1+1=2

A governing unchanging law from the beginning of time to the end of space.

Shukur'Allah I have an equation that answers it all and beyond. It's the theory of absolute infinity and all shown without surpassing any of our governing laws. The beauty of it is in its simplicity. It shows beyond our limits yet explains that our limits we can not see beyond.

This is not infinitesimal or infinities within our existing boundaries as I will show.

So starting with the basics and the limits of our mathematics, our governing laws.

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12....

Our numerical system has potentially a never ending amount of numbers. The more you count, the more we can plus another one.

Potentially an infinite amount, but in truth, only one number does exist

**The number "1"**

> E.g 1 + 1 + 1 = 3

That is because "1" explains itself and every other number. In fact, every number is a repetition (more precisely a reproduction) of the number "1". Not only does it explain every whole number but it also explains every type of number.

For example, a fraction or a decimal point is a "part of "1"".

> 50% = of 1
>
> 1/2 = of 1
>
> 0.5 = of 1

**What's so special about "1" is it is also complete**

> 1 = 100%

In maths, when something is complete It MUST have a bound and an end. In maths this is signified with brackets ( )

> ( <------bound, beginning
>
> ) <------end, finish

*****(We do not use the brackets because we consider it common knowledge.)

In maths we rarely use it but Brackets explain grouping pairs or completion in maths. That is why brackets are done first in arithmetical equation

e.g

> (3+2) x (3+1) = 20
>
> or
>
> (5) x (4) = (20)

**One is 100% completely bounded and ended to itself.**

> (1) or (100%)

Hence this instantly means "(1)", the number "1" is finite because it has finite restrictions. **ANYTHING that can be calculated is**. Instantly our universe becomes finite (1) even if it has potentially infinite possibilities (∞).

> 1 = 100% = everything, hence the answer to theory of everything must
>   be simply (1)

Our current understanding of the Infinite and all the different size infinities that we come to know are merely potential infinities of what number 1 can explain. It's just studying the infinite possibilities within (1). Even if there were multiverses, they would all still be encompassed by another greater (1)

> Infinity = ∞

Infinity is a concept and not a number. It is something boundless/endless and unrestricted (beyond the brackets)

If we accept ...

> (∞)

...as a true statement then it would literally be the greatest oxymoron (contradiction) to ever exist. How can the unrestricted concept be restricted?

To make matters worse, **there is also another restriction of the number (1)**

That is because by itself can not do much. It needs a medium or a language to communicate.

Multiply, divide, square root etc are all fancy and group methods of doing the core symbols of maths.

Addition and subtraction

> '+ -'

Just like (1),

(+|-) addition and subtraction can explain themselves and every other type of calculations.

Example

> (1+1+1) + (1+1+1) = (1+1+1+1+1+1)

**So inside every (1) we have (+|-).**

E.g

> Man = (1)
>
> And he has (+|-) within himself.

Think of anything Positive and negative, Addition Subtraction, Time space, Proton electron, Good Bad, Right Wrong, Light Dark

We can even say

Yin Yang for good measure

All we have is equal and opposites and one can not exist without the other. Black exists because of white and vice versa.

Think of anything, chemistry, biology, physics even non-scientific subjects like morale; you can even say from a materialistic moral point of view, water is our greatest asset, the reason for life yet, our greatest restriction.

Anything from a positive and a negative within a finite position can be explained quite easily.

> (+ -) within (1)

Now to make it interesting..........

Scientifically we know we are living in 1 x (E=mc2), we are restricted.

My question is say we calculated everything that exists in our (1) universe.

Hypothetically let's say

> everything = (100)

What would be

> 1 + (100) = ?

It can not be 101

Reason

Everything has already been calculated and it equalled (100)

Let me rephrase the question

from my brief explanation earlier what would be

> 1 + (finite)
>
> 1 + (maths)
>
> 1 + (1)
>
> 1 + (universe)
>
> 1 + (everything)
>
> 1 + (100%)
>
> 1 + (E=mc2)
>
> 1 + (+|-)
>
> ????

It must be something outside of the bound and end (brackets)

Our concept of this is called

> Absolute (meaning 100%)
>
> Infinity ∞  (meaning beyond any boundaries)

To reiterate ∞  is a concept and not a number so it must be beyond all bounds "(" and ends ")"

So in an equation

> 1 + (1) = ∞

Or as explained before the core language of (1) is maths (+|-)

The theory of Absolute Infinity

> 1 + (+|-) = ∞

Even though I have not surpassed our laws of mathematics, it displays something beyond mathematics.

**What so special about this equation?**

**AGREES WITH SCIENCE:**

---

Quote: "If an object tries to travel 186,000 miles per second, its mass becomes infinite, and so does the energy required to move it. For this reason, no normal object can travel as fast or faster than the speed of light."

So if something exceeds this limit (1) its mass becomes infinite.

> 1 + (1) = ∞

---

> Mathematics studies the (+ | - ) laws to understand the (1) value.
>
> Science studies the (1) value to understand the ( + | - ) laws.

---

Quantum Mechanics states for nothing to create something, laws must be in place for nothing to produce something.

The equation covers this aspect quite easily.

A law is something that governs its subjects. It is not an actual physical entity and can not be expressed as the value 1.

It is, however, an addition which must preexist our mathematical restrictions, as quantum mechanics states.

> '+ ( + | - )' This is the equation of Quantum mechanics,
>
> And this '(+|-)' is what governing physics studies

---

RELIGION
It explain outside of our brackets

God is complete 1

> 100%

Yet he is incomprehensible

> ∞

It explains that we have the option of either choosing a + path or - negative

If on the day of judgment "=" (The day of TOTALLING/Tallying/equal sign)

our good deeds outweigh our bad

> 1 + ( + > - ) = + ∞

You will end up in eternal positive or heaven

or respectively

> 1 + ( + < -) = - ∞

Hell

> God 1 = ∞
>
> Created +
>
> Everything (+ - )
>
> and he only gives + "good" to all creation
>
> and everything (1) was made in pairs (+ - )

---

Prisca Theologia

> +(+|-) Atheist, understand natural law exist and Quanta
>
> (∞)=∞ Pantheist, the universe is God
>
> (1)=∞ Buddha said, look within yourself (1) and find your personal (∞)
>   nirvana.
>
> ( 1 + (+|-) = ∞) Christianity,
>
> father 1=∞
>
> holy spirit +
>
> son (+|-)

Exterior brackets trinity

(holy spirit is the deliverer of the law, the son is earthly bound (+-) son)

Even though Jesus can have potentially have an (∞) possibilities within him, he can never be God. That is why he always said the father ∞ is greater than I (1)

Islam

> Surah 112
>
> Say he is one
>
> 1
>
> on all whom depend +
>
> he begets not, (+)
>
> nor is begotten (-)
>
> (+|-)
>
> and none is like him ∞

within the ayat he mentions his name as l-Samadu meaning the Eternal the Absolute

It is everywhere (on every page in every Surah) in the Quran

It doesn't matter if you call this concept Allah, God, Absolute Infinite. 
What's important to understand is that a concept beyond anything calculable (including all the potential infinities) does exist, as Cantor proclaimed.

Cantor actually coined the word "transfinite" in an attempt to distinguish the various levels of infinite numbers from an Absolute Infinity 100% ∞ , an incomprehensible concept beyond mathematics itself, which then Cantor effectively equated with God (he saw no contradiction between his mathematics and the traditional concept of God)

**IN RESPONSE TO Pi or other paradoxes**

For all those who are going to give the response what about irrational numbers like Pi or other infinity paradoxes, well.....

This equation is explaining the Absolute Infinite beyond any restricting and governing laws.

Pi is restricted to and only potentially infinite.

To explain, Pi is the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter and is restricted to the circle's circumference. It is within a 100% complete and enclosing "circle".

Same goes for every type and size of infinite we know.

For example, take the Hilbert hotel paradox, It is still within a hotel.

This infinite is bounded and ended by the governing laws of its confinements. When Time/Space ends, the numbers within it must end with it.

Absolute Infinity can not be governed or restricted by numerical properties

Also 3.1415926535... is basically (1)+(1)+(1)

We have "3" individual 100% complete (1)s and we are 0.85840734641021... away from the next complete (1), or the 4th (1)

**And for anyone who wants to argue for zero**

Then I ask what is 0?

Cause if we mean something was there and then wasn't then it never can be 0 and if it never existed we wouldn't know the 0 of it exists

Something that exists can not "not" exist because it has existed.

If the entity is removed it is the absence of an existence, not uncreated.

Nothing can only exist because it was something.

Something can never become nothing because it was once something and nothing can not be subtracted unless it becomes an additional something.

As soon as we label it nothing, it becomes something even if there is nothing there. The reason is when we identify its nothing, we give a no value (even if its nothing) within mathematical laws.

This doesn't only apply to physical or tangible entities.

For example, we can create (or add-on) using our imagination. The unique imaginative something that we created exists at a certain time within your space so even if forgotten and never remembered again, it can never become nothing, only the addition it supplied is removed.

However, even this imaginative something is still restricted and can only be created because of our experiences.

We can not imagine what someone else imagines nor can we conjure up something unimaginable because everything you imagine is subject to your experiences or, your moment in time within the space of your life.

E.g

Say I dreamt of a monster in my childhood.

Did that monster ever exist?

Actually yes, even though I just imagined it subconsciously it existed and was definable at that present time, even if none of the details can be remembered or is totally forgotten.

I.e it must be recorded for that particular time of my space

More so, for me just to give the above example I am creating something.

I've defined a nonexistent for example purposes so even if I never had any dreams of a monster in my life, it still exists because of my example.

Hence we can never identify "Absolute Zero" for as soon as we label "it", "it" becomes the absence of something rather than becoming from nothing.

Thanks for listening

∞ bless you all

Comment: Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](//islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](//islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in our [help center](//islam.stackexchange.com/help). What is your question?

Comment: My question is pretty simple. Can God who is the truth be proven with the language of the truth, mathematics (as I have tried to do above) ?

Comment: This is not a question, it is an answer... This is not a place to do dawah. If someone asked this question it would be a possible answer.

Comment: The text in the question is way too long.

Comment: ex falso quodlibet!

Comment: A question can be asked in numerous ways. I established the truth of why I think it can and must explain Allah and now I ask the question has the equation got it right or not? Is this the explanation of Allah in simple mathematics without surpassing any of our laws?

Answer (score 3):

The post is one mathematical misunderstanding after another.  If you're allowed to do whatever you want with numbers, you can prove and/or disprove whatever you want.

Here's a few blatant errors:

- > Our numerical system has potentially a never ending amount of numbers.

  should say "there are infinitely many natural numbers".
- > ... only one number does exist ...

  would imply that 2 = 1 (because only one number exists).  While it's true in **Z**<sub>1</sub>, it's not true in the natural numbers.
- > That is because "1" explains itself and every other number.

  "explain" undefined; what's considered a "[number](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/494854/91818)" undefined (although presumably it's circularly defined those numbers which are "explained" by 1).
- > 50% = of 1

  appears to be a syntax error
- > "1" ... it is also complete

  "complete" undefined
- > In maths, when something is complete It MUST have a bound and an end. In maths this is signified with brackets ( )

  We use brackets to indicate the order of operations in arithmetic.  It's unclear what this has to do with anything being "complete".
- > One is 100% completely bounded and ended to itself.

  This appears to the notion of a "[nullary operation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273330/why-is-a-nullary-operation-a-special-element-usually-0-or-1)" in abstract algebra (with added mysticism).
- > Instantly our universe becomes finite (1) even if it has potentially infinite possibilities (∞).

  Something mathematically deep requires more than just changing the notation.  In this case, adding brackets adds nothing more than, well, brackets.
- > 1 = 100% = everything, hence the answer to theory of everything must be simply (1)

  [image: Then a miracle occurs]
- > Our current understanding of the Infinite and all the different size infinities that we come to know are merely potential infinities of what number 1 can explain.

  The fact that there's strictly more real numbers than natural numbers is a strong indication that 1 doesn't "explain" everything, for whatever definition of "explain" you're using.
- > Even if there were multiverses, they would all still be encompassed by another greater (1)

  Wait, now we've jumped to hypothetical physics?
- > If we accept ... (∞) ... as a true statement then it would literally be the greatest oxymoron (contradiction) to ever exist.

  That's not how brackets work.
- > Multiply, divide, square root etc are all fancy and group methods of doing the core symbols of maths.

  Not they're not.  See, e.g. [If multiplication is not repeated addition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/64488/91818).
- > Man = (1)

  What?

Comment: **<comments deleted>**. Comments should primarily be used to ask for more information and suggest improvements. Not discussions. Take it [chat] if you want to do so. And remember the [**Be Nice**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#nice) policy at **all** times.